# Firebase Admin SDK : Verifying ID tokens from the REST API

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to verify Id tokens received by signing in with the REST API for authentication by using the `verifyIdToken(idToken)` method in the Admin SDK but instead of getting the decoded token I get the error:

> Firebase ID token has incorrect "iss" (issuer) claim. Expected "https://securetoken.google.com/"" but got "https://identitytoolkit.google.com/". Make sure the ID token comes from the same Firebase project as the service account used to authenticate this SDK. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.

As I said above I'm getting my token from the REST API, so I was expecting this to work.
The response I get from the API is this:

```
{
    "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse",
    "localId": "pu0yjIc8tnR85X2gERdtLx684DK2",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "displayName": "",
    "idToken": "<token-id>",
    "registered": true
}
```

Is this considered a custom token? if so, how can I verify it?

Comment: Consider `idToken` expiration time is small about one hour.

Comment: try to validate your idToken by this endpoint, https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?{idToken}

Comment: @KhaledLela Can you give me a link to the Docs for this endpoint?

Comment: Unfortunately, ID tokens returned by the `verifyPassword` endpoint, are not Firebase ID tokens.

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka So how would I verify this tokens?

Comment: You will have to find some other way than using the Firebase Admin SDK. Possibly using the endpoint mentioned by @KhaledLela

Comment: @SamuelE. Just pass `idToken` to your server and verify it using endpoint mentioned on my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51275686/1283715) , Consider to make regular register to that user after verification pass as `idToken` has short lifetime about 1hr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Sep 2018, the issuer of the ID Token returned by REST API seems to be changed from `https://identitytoolkit.google.com/` to `https://securetoken.google.com/`. And I can successfully verify this id token in firebase admin SDK.

[Edit]: The firebase admin SDK still **fails** to verify the **Facebook** ID Token returned by identitytoolkit's verifyAssertion REST API.

Comment: Thank you for the update, I know you answered a while ago but I marked it as the accepted answer.

Comment: would you share your answer detail for this issue?

Comment: Also, don't forget to include  `"returnSecureToken":true` within the request body.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google Developer](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth)

- Calling the tokeninfo endpoint

> An easy way to validate an ID token for debugging and low-volume use
>   is to use the tokeninfo endpoint. Calling this endpoint involves an
>   additional network request that does most of the validation for you,
>   but introduces some latency and the potential for network errors.
>
> To validate an ID token using the tokeninfo endpoint, make an HTTPS
>   POST or GET request to the endpoint, and pass your ID token in the
>   id_token parameter. For example, to validate the token "XYZ123", make
>   the following GET request:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123

```
{
 // These six fields are included in all Google ID Tokens.
 "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
 "sub": "110169484474386276334",
 "azp": "1008719970978-hb24n2dstb40o45d4feuo2ukqmcc6381.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "aud": "1008719970978-hb24n2dstb40o45d4feuo2ukqmcc6381.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "iat": "1433978353",
 "exp": "1433981953",

 // These seven fields are only included when the user has granted the "profile" and
 // "email" OAuth scopes to the application.
 "email": "testuser@gmail.com",
 "email_verified": "true",
 "name" : "Test User",
 "picture": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-kYgzyAWpZzJ/ABCDEFGHI/AAAJKLMNOP/tIXL9Ir44LE/s99-c/photo.jpg",
 "given_name": "Test",
 "family_name": "User",
 "locale": "en"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's unfortunate that a better solution is not supported by the official Admin SDK